# Splash screen flickers during every boot

Tags: 12.10

Splash screen flickers heavily during boot on my dell inspiron N5010 laptop,but disappears after some time by press Esc button(several times)..This happens everytime I boot...
The problem exists in all linux-distros
currently on ubuntu 12.10 64 bit... My laptop doesnt hav any dedicated graphics card but oly intel hd 3000

I hav enclosed boot.log,Dmesg.log ,Xorg.log and my system info respectively

[Boot.log](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/46854640/Boot.log)

[Xorg.log](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/46854640/Dmesg.log)

Comment: You could try to remove splash from the boot part: sudo nano /etc/default/grub and remove GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash" splash from this line.

Comment: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/46854640/Xorg.log
--------------------------------------------
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/46854640/System%20info

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a USB keyboard/Mouse/Wifi receiver? I had this same issue whenever I had my logitech wireless keyboard and mouse hooked up. The problem was fixed by removing it...

Comment: i hav usb keyboard and mouse

Comment: @Dr_Bunsen i removed GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash" but still splash screen flickers

Comment: @Dr_Bunsen after removing GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"  the flickering time was reduced but still ther splash screen was flickering

Answer (score 1):

Put The following line instead of:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

in `/etc/default/grub` :

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"
```

Save it. And run `sudo update-grub`

It usually works.

Comment: well doing so the flickering wil reduce a bit but still its present...moreover using "quiet splash nomodeset" untity starts running in 2d once booted

Comment: That kinda worked but took my computer's ability to reduce screen brightness. Not good.

Answer (score 0):

#### Summary:

Actually, you should remove everything from **GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"**, so it will become **GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""**.

---

#### Temporary solution:

Before logging in (during boot process):

Press <kbd>E</kbd> in the Grub menu while Ubuntu is selected.

Update the **GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"** portion of the file
to **GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""**.

Press F10 to boot.

---

#### Permanent solution:

After logging in:

```
sudo apt install gedit
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Update the **GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"** portion of the file
to **GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""**

Then,

```
sudo update-grub
```