# "dev/sda1: clean, ..." This message appears after I startup my laptop, then it won't continue booting

Tags: boot, startup

[image]

```
dev/sda1: clean, 552599/6111232 files, 7119295/24414464 blocks
```

After I turn on my laptop this message appears. The system never boots, the message just stays there.

Comment: This is a normal startup message. It lets you know that there are no filesystem errors.

Comment: this message does not disappear how can try this solution

Comment: @Pilot6 OK?  but how can use OS

Comment: Oh, I see http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it

Comment: @YahiaEl-Dow please see my answer... it's incomplete right now, but let me know the results, and I'll finish the answer.

Comment: thanks a lot  @heynnema I can't try ur solution now because I re-install ubuntu again

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Boot message about disk clean: Can it indicate bad disk?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/987024/boot-message-about-disk-clean-can-it-indicate-bad-disk)

Comment: I get a message like this and ubuntu boots to the desktop. But it seems display driver is not working. Wifi is also not working. What should I do?

Comment: For those folks who tried installing lightgdm and didn't work, you might see a message `/dev/nvme3/: clean` and you waited for a long time. 

Try these commands. (Alt + F2 to login, if you are still stuck).
`sudo service gdm3 status` (in you case it might be gdm)

If its not already running try:
`sudo service gdm3 start`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: Worked for me: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop`

Comment: @heynnema this message doesn't disappear and stucks there!

Comment: @BenyaminJafari Please start a new question.

Comment: @heynnema this question was asked three times before without any comprehensive answer. (e.g. [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1258033/ubuntu-get-stuck-at-dev-sda6-clean-message-with-some-number-on-bootup-help))

Comment: I bypassed this problem by disabling the discrete graphics card (Nvidia) in BIOS.

Comment: @BenyaminJafari Then you either have Secure Boot enabled, or the wrong/old Nvidia driver installed. And yes. this question has been asked a 1000 times before, and although the fix may be similar, it still required that you start a new question, instead of hanging on an old question from 2017.

Comment: @heynnema according to the StackExchange policy it would not be appropriate to ask a duplicated question again. you will encounter with close the question in this case. Also from the highest score of the top answer which is half of the question score, indicates that this problem still remains and hasn't been solved properly since 2017!

Comment: @BenyaminJafari Well, I've given you the probable solution in my last comment... you can try it if you wish... but I'm not here to argue SE Policy with you.

Comment: As the problem is related to the ***graphics driver*** failing to load the ***boot splash screen***, you can consider my [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1386363/1064325) on flickering screen.

Answer (score 97):

I have had this problem occur a few times, and every time it was ODDLY **Nvidia's fault** - yes **COUNTER-INTUITIVELY**

If in Ubuntu after a long painful reboot run:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
```

or if locked try Ubuntu's awesome way of troubleshooting and try:
Ctrl+Alt+F1 through F7 to get to "TTY1-7" and run the same thing.
Reboot for good measure, and re-install Nvidia's Proprietary Drivers.

Comment: Please note, that  the  `/dev/sda1:clean` message comes from `fsck` being run at boot time (see [answer here](https://askubuntu.com/q/987024/295286)). The fact that OP's system wouldn't boot has no relation to the message.  Booting issue was likely due to improper graphics driver being used, which is why this answer worked for some people.

Comment: But what if we need NVIDIA, e.g. if we're using their GPU?

Comment: @mikewhatever  how are you so sure?! This happened to me twice already and it's just after a kernel update. The nvidia module goes missing and the system never finishes booting. Removing the driver (to clean anything that reamined) and then installing it again (thus creating a module for the new kernel) solves the issue. I'd be glad if you can prove it has nothing to do with that and explain us why. This is not "nonsense".

Comment: I'd be glad to prove it, if you can arrange access to your PC for evaluation. Without that, asking for something like that poses an impossible task. The nvidia module should get auto-rebuilt by dkms after a kernel update. It's been working for me for many years on multiple PCs with different Nvidia cards. I've never ever had to remove the driver and reinstall.

Comment: Wow, it worked. I actually was thinking of removing Nvidia, but it was a little further down on my list, just under "Open computer case and jiggle some wires to see if anything was loose" and "apply hammer to motherboard with extreme force". Glad I found this post because I'd exhausted all attempts to fix/bypass fsck.

Comment: To contradict @mikewhatever, this worked for me as well. Thank you!

Comment: @bradtgmurray Hi Brad, I am glad the answer worked for you, but I think you've had a different problem. Please note that my comment above is only related to this answer as a response to the original question. To reiterate, there is no mention of Nvidia by the OP, and the boot message is completely harmless. If you wish to "contradict" any of those statements, please give it a try. Good luck.

Comment: Worked on Ubuntu 20.04, thinkpad t480 with mx150. I really hate nvidia drivers, they are super buggy and causing problems ever since.

Comment: This helped only when I properly reinstalled Nvidia drivers, as recommended at https://askubuntu.com/a/1218483/750140

Comment: It's not working on my Thinkpad E450C Ubuntu 20.04. Any other solution?

Comment: This worked on Ubuntu 20.04 (Regolith) HP Pavilion X360 14-cd0017ns

Comment: Well ladida, get this, I've been having the same issue in recent times couldn't for the life of me figure why, and to you point Nvidia is acting up, when I plugged my monitor into my onboard display It turns out the system booted fine in the background, but on my screen plugged into my Nvidia card, it displayed this message. Wut!?!?!

Comment: This worked for me as well. Thanks so much for this answer.

Answer (score 36):

I experienced the same problem; though Mark's (top answer) solution didn't immediately work (since <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> etc. brings up a flickering TTYL which is nearly impossible to use), his suggested cause was correct, as it was a problem with the nvidia driver.

Also for beginners like me, here's the fool-proof step-by-step solution:

1. Boot into safe mode (recovery mode). Enter this mode by holding the left shift key when the computer starts.
2. in terminal, type:

   `sudo apt-get purge nvidia*`

   `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` #Make sure you have internet connection

Other solutions suggested elsewhere didn't work (e.g. installing `boot-repair` or `sudo apt-get update`)

(This worked on my dual booted computer (Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04)

my error message was `/dev/nvme0n1p5: clean, nnn/nnn files, nnn/nnn blocks`

Comment: I tried many things (including changing my display manager).
`sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` is what finally worked for me, thank you!

Comment: It worked for me in normal mode also, not necessarily in safe mode.

Comment: `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoninstall` gave me "No drivers found for installation"

Comment: Watch out, I had the origin of my ubuntu software PPA pointed to my country and when I did sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall  I lost ethernet and wifi drivers and probably others. The reason is supposed to be is that the repository of my country is outdated. The following answer helped me get them back:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1286738/no-wi-fi-settings-or-connection-after-switching-to-nvidia-graphics-driver

Comment: I got stuck and waited for over half a hour so I tried this. It worked, saved my day!

Answer (score 24):

**I solved this by fixing the installation of my display manager (gdm3)**

```
sudo apt install gdm3
```

**Story behind this**:

I was upgrading from Ubuntu 18 to 20.
I have dual OS installed (Ubuntu 20 and Windows 10) on my Xiaomi laptop, no nvidia or AMD graphics card, Intel Core i5 8th gen.

1. **Log in to your terminal**

   You can do this via reboot and choose recovery mode or press <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f2</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f2</kbd> when the screen is stuck
2. **Connect to a network**
   You can do this using

   ```
   iwconfig <your-wifi-adapter> essid <network-name> key <network-password>
   ```
3. **Do basic recovery steps**

   ```
   sudo apt update
   sudo apt clean
   sudo apt autoremove
   sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
   sudo dpkg --configure -a
   sudo apt install -f
   ```

   This should do the trick, but just to make sure, continue to the next step.
4. **Check display manager**

   ```
   $ cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager
   /usr/sbin/gdm3
   ```

   Then `systemctl status display-manager` or `/etc/init.d/gdm3 status` make sure your display manager's status is active **then** `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3`.

   If it shows

   ```
   /usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure: gconf2 is broken or not fully installed
   ```

   then there is your problem.
5. **Fix the broken package**

   ```
   sudo apt install gdm3
   ```

Comment: This is the one that resolved the issue for me. Mine had been caused by removing `python3-*` packages, to upgrade from 3.8 to 3.9 on the system install. This unexpectedly uninstalled a bunch of other packages along with it, `gdm3` among them.

Answer (score 19):

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f2</kbd> or <kbd>f3</kbd>

- login with your account
- type `sudo apt-get update` (enter password when prompted)
- type `sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-intel`
- reboot

Comment: or type `journalctl` and check what is going on there

Comment: But why does `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`F2` help login?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. Before shutting down, the system noted: "low disk space".

I solved it by using an Ubuntu live disk (USB). I deleted files on the HDD to free space, then Ubuntu restarted as usual.

Comment: Fixed it for me, I switched to a terminal with ctrl+alt+F1 and deleted some big files

Comment: Same for me, I did the same as Johannes and ran some commands to remove cache, to remove packages with sudo apt-get clean             sudo apt-get autoclean   sudo journalctl --vacuum-time=2d     sudo apt-get autoremove --purge

Comment: Disk space was also the issue for me. I booted in recovery mode and used 'clean' to remove old installation files, which gave me enough to boot successfully.

Answer (score 4):

I faced same problem on Ubuntu 20.04; it was also because Nvidia driver. I just re-installed the driver and it started working properly.

```
sudo apt install --reinstall nvidia-settings
```

Comment: magically this helped me to get the UI back and I can login now. (20.04)

Answer (score 2):

1. Let's first check your file system for errors.

   To check the file system on your Ubuntu partition...

   - boot to the GRUB menu
   - choose Advanced Options
   - choose Recovery mode
   - choose Root access
   - at the # prompt, type `sudo fsck -f /`
   - repeat the fsck command if there were errors
   - type `reboot`

   If for some reason you can't do the above...

   - boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
   - start `gparted` and determine which /dev/sdaX is your Ubuntu partition
   - quit `gparted`
   - open a `terminal` window
   - type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdaX` # replacing X with the number you found earlier
   - repeat the fsck command if there were errors
   - type `reboot`
2. If step 1. doesn't fix your problem, then do this.

   - boot to the GRUB menu
   - choose Advanced Options
   - choose Recovery mode
   - choose Root access
   - at the # prompt, type:
   - `sudo blkid`
   - `sudo cat /etc/fstab`
   - edit your question to include the output from the two previous commands
   - type `reboot`
3. pending fix here...
4. If you dual boot with Windows, then do this in Windows.

   - open the Power control panel
   - click on `change what the power buttons do`
   - click on `change options that are unavailable`
   - uncheck `fast start`
   - close the Power control panel
   - open an administrative command prompt window
   - type `powercfg /h off` *(turns off hibernation)*
   - type `chkdsk /f c:`
   - approve that chkdsk runs at next boot time
   - reboot Windows

Comment: Run these steps and tell me the result, and I'll finish the answer with the final fix.

Comment: I have the same problem, it shows me the same /dev/sda1: clean..... message when I run the sudo fsck command. I type fsck and then reboot, however the problem still persists. I am not dual booting, I intend to have one OS that is Lubuntu on my 8 yr old netbook. Can you suggest what to do next

Comment: @TransistorOverlord please start a new question. Provide as much detail as possible. Describe exactly what you've tried to fix the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Neither of the answers worked for me. I have an old laptop with an Atom processor without Nvidia graphics. Thus, I've adopted an alternative solution with `nomodeset` mode as follows:

- In installation scene, press <kbd>F6</kbd>, use arrow keys to go down to `nomodeset`, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. An `x` will appear to its left. Then press <kbd>Esc</kbd>, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to "Try Ubuntu without installing" or "Install it".

---

[UPDATE]

I got into trouble with another laptop (ThinkPad T430) and I fixed that by disabling the discrete graphic card (Nvidia) in BIOS.

Answer (score 2):

A mechanical issue with the hard drive can trigger an fsck execution on boot and that could be the cause of an error message of the following type:

```
dev/sdaX: clean, ******/******* files, *******/******** blocks
```

If the other solutions to this question don't work try swapping the hard drive with another replacement hard drive. It should also be noted that even low-priced budget SSDs have better performance than HDDs.

Comment: This message don't means a mechanical issue of any type. Please see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/987024/boot-message-about-disk-clean-can-it-indicate-bad-disk

Comment: @lestcape Your comment is a false claim. From the accepted answer to your linked question (2nd to last paragraph): "there are other potential causes of fsck appearing on boot ( unclean unmount of the filesystem, cable or **failing HDD sectors** ,etc. )".

Comment: Well, i think you original answer is certainly right, because you said the opposite i said. I said: "This message don't means a mechanical issue of any type", and is true, because it only means that fsck was executed. But certainly you said the opposite: "A mechanical issue with the hard drive can cause an error message" and this could be rigth, because a mechanical issue can trigger an fsck execution on boot and that could be the cause of the message.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstood what you really said, you also get my upvote now.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this will work for everyone but I managed to fix this by removing every occurrence of `nomodeset` from `/etc/default/grub` file and then by executing `sudo update-grub`.

This was because `nomodeset` disables the use of any graphic driver. I disabled my `nouveau` drivers before installing nvidia ones.

**Though this might not be the case with everyone.**

Comment: Thanks, yes that make sense too. I have alienware 13 R-3, To install ubuntu I added nomodeset to enable ubuntu os to load. Once I installed nvidia driver, I was getting the above error. So on grub I pressed e for edit and removed the nomodeset and ctrl+x to rebboot. After that I got desktop all fine.

Answer (score 1):

I reinstalled Nvidia drivers and the PC started working:

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f2</kbd> or <kbd>f3</kbd>

- Log in with your account
- Run these commands:

  ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
   sudo apt update 
   sudo apt install nvidia-settings
  ```
- Reboot

(thanks to @Shahad and his solution at https://askubuntu.com/a/1218483/750140)

Comment: how do i connect my ubuntu  20.04 to internet in recovery mode ??

Comment: But why does `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`F2` help login? If it helps login, then isn't it the solution without requiring install or uninstall anything (yes, I understand I have to press the keys every time I boot, but it isn't much hurdle)?

Answer (score 1):

For AMD users:

- Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f2</kbd>
- Log in to your account
- Uninstall your AMD drivers by using either of these commands, depending on your drivers.

  ```
  amdgpu-pro-uninstall
  ```

  or

  ```
  amdgpu-uninstall
  ```
- Do a `reboot`
- After successfully logging in, reinstall your drivers.

Answer (score 1):

The closest answer I found helpful to solve my problem was [this one](https://askubuntu.com/a/882960/869785) and I hope it will help you too

I just had a similar problem and I found problem was that the UUID for the EFI partition in `/etc/fstab` is not correct. I fixed it using the following:

Boot using live system USB/CD, open terminal, and check UUIDs for partitions root and EFI

```
lsblk -f
```

Use `fdisk` to know which is the EFI partition and make sure it's in the correct format (EFI system partition)

```
fdisk -l /dev/sdX
```

Mount the root partition `/dev/sdXX` into `/mnt`

```
mount /dev/sdXX /mnt
```

then check the fstab file

```
cat /mnt/etc/fstab
```

If the UUID values are different, edit the value in the fstab file to match the correct UUID

use nano, gedit, vi, or whatever you want to edit and save fstab and reboot

that worked for me.

I believe the values changed because I installed Windows after installing Linux in my case.

Answer (score 1):

If you have these symptoms:

- Booting stops at "dev/sda1: clean..." or "/dev/nvme0n1p2: clean"
- Not an Nvidia gpu (e.g. you have an AMD graphics card)
- Default video driver installation (e.g. you did not install custom amd drivers yourself)
- You are able to start a tty session using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f2</kbd>

Then there is a chance that GNOME Display Manager is not starting for some reason (eg due to a recent Ubuntu update).

To check:

- Start a tty session: <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f2</kbd>
- Login to your account
- Typing `systemctl status display-manager` gives an error or shows that the GNOME Display Manager is not both loaded and active.
- As alternative to the previous step, you could also try looking in syslog file to see if gdm is starting up (eg `cat /var/log/syslog | grep "Starting GNOME Display Manager"`)

If so, then type

- `sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop` to reinstall
- `reboot`

Comment: If I am able to login via Ctrl+Alt+F2, then isn't it the solution? It is not too much hurdle to press those keys!

Comment: @RawnakYazdani - You are right if your goal was to open access a terminal/tty on boot. But if your goal was to start the Ubuntu GUI on boot, then accessing tty session is only the first part of the solution.

Answer (score 1):

My issue was due to large size of Syslog file in `/var/log/syslog`. It has filled my HDD. So I have fixed it by the following steps.

- boot with live USB
- locate to `/var/log/Syslog` in your HDD
- remove the file
- reboot

For more info see [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/747022/1058650) answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with fresh install of 18.04.3 desktop on proxmox 6.1
Had to change to vmware compatible graphics for the VM before it would work..

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid running fsck by booting into recovery mode and editing the file /etc/fstab to temporarily change the final 1 to 0 for the affected partition:

```
sudo nano /etc/fstab
```

Then reboot. If that gives a blank screen instead, reboot again, and press 'e' at the Grub menu. This time, omit the kernel parameters 'quiet splash' before resuming boot. You might get more helpful information to see where it is getting stuck - probably at the next step to do with gdm (or other login manager being used), or the system logging service. If you fail to rescue the existing installation, do a fresh installation using a wired internet connection so that it installs, makes the right settings, and updates correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Very specific solution for me:

In recovery mode, disable automatic login for your user. I found it will make Ubuntu VM stuck at startup if you have Home folder encryption active and enable automatic login.

Answer (score 0):

Hi for me the answer was totally different my issue was i was having a different kernel version so the grub was loading a different version of the kernel on changing the kernel to latest one fixed the issue to update the kernal i used mainline

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cappelikan/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install mainline
```

once kernel was installed i uninstalled the old kernel and switched to new one
at the time it was 6.4.8 and when i checked after that the tool mainline updated the grub also to use the new kernal and the issue was fixed, this might not be the issue with all the case but this fixed for me if someone has the same issue you can also resolve this using this method
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem, but in my case the problem was the hard drive being too full.

I solved it by:

1. starting ubuntu in console mode:

a) when the grub starts press the key "e" for edit.
b) add a `3` after `quiet splash`. So that it reads  `quiet splash 3`

2. Once you can log in console mode, delete a big useless file with `rm big-useless-file`
3. Restart the computer.

This solved the issue for me. I realized the disk was too full because I tried `sudo apt-get update`, which failed with an error telling me that the disk was full.