# Update issue with Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS

Tags: 16.04

I'm upgrading from Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS to Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS in my desktop. 
After that in my screen, I see one message:

/dev/sda2 clean XXXX/YYY files, ZZZZ/SSSS blocks.

After that, Nothing is showing in the screen.

At the same time, I am able to ssh to my desktop. I cannt update using command. For example,

```
sudo apt-get update
apt-get: relocation error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapt-pkg.so.5.0: symbol _ZNKSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE7compareERKS4_, version GLIBCXX_3.4.21 not defined in file libstdc++.so.6 with link time reference
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: I'm able to get the grub2. I checked with ls command. The result shows some error in (hd1) error. Failure reading sector 0xfc from 'hd1'

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["dev/sda1: clean, ..." This message appears after I startup my laptop, then it won't continue booting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/882385/dev-sda1-clean-this-message-appears-after-i-startup-my-laptop-then-it-w)