# Getting dev/sda1: clean ... after update-rc.d

Tags: 16.04, boot, startup, fsck

I was trying to make a program start at startup. Ubuntu 16.04. 
I did following:

```
Opened Terminal 
cd /etc/init.d 
sudo gedit 

added:
#!/bin/bash
# /etc/init.d/cmdtrm
echo password | sudo -S /usr/master/bin/trmf

saved file as cmdtrm

sudo update-rc.d cmdtrm defaults
sudo chmod +x cmdtrm

Rebooted machine
```

After rebooting, I'm getting the following on screen:

> /dev/sda1: clean, xxxxx/xxxx files, xxxxx/xxxxx blocks

[image]

And it just stays. Nothing happens.

The program has started in the background. I know this since the program connects to my server.

[This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/882385/dev-sda1-clean-this-message-appears-after-i-startup-my-laptop-then-it-wont-c) has some answers, but I'm not sure how should I approach in my case.

How can I make Ubuntu boot properly? Do I need to terminate the program? How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was due to some lines that I had added in /etc/security/limits.conf

On the black screen, I pressed Ctrl+Alt+F1, then

```
sudo vi /etc/security/limits.conf
```

removed the two lines, saved and rebooted.

Ubuntu rebooted normally.