# Dell laptop running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS overheating problem and fans running fast

Tags: nvidia, 20.04, dell, overheating

While my PC is a pretty decent one and it came up with Ubuntu preinstalled the overheating problem was getting out of hand. I tried so many things like `tlp` `thermald` but none worked.

Turns out when NVIDIA is set on Performance Mode in NVIDIA X Server settings it causes the PC to try and use the GPU resources too much. And it was set to Performance Mode by default.

Inspired by [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1053840/continuous-running-of-fans-overheating-on-dell-xps-15-9560) post I could fix it, now I don't even hear the fans and I have no issue running GPU intensive stuff (Not games thought)

[NVIDIA X Server Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8wbw.png)

For anyone out there having a similar issue please try this, it might save you a ton of time!

Comment: I have the same issue on a Dell Precision 3480. After a short usage or while watching a video the Fans go crazy with an overheating on the right part of the laptop. My issue is the same as the one you have described. I have checked the nvidia settings but I have no possibility to choose the GPU performance. The dell technician has just changed the Fans but nothing changed so I guess this is software or motherboard related. Any infos is welcome !

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR Check NVIDIA X Server Settings and change it from Performance Mode to either Power Saving Mode or On-Demand.

Comment: I did that, it crushed my nvidia drivers and left me with a login loop... after a while I could restore the drivers and switched to intel...still overheating...

Answer (score 0):

I used to have overheating problem which I was able to trace and it related to video driver. Try reducing screen resolution/upgrading the driver, if that works.