# Ubuntu 18.04 stuck at start-up - probably not properly unmounted?

Tags: boot, grub2, mount, fstab

When ubuntu is started, the grub menu pops up. When I select "Ubuntu", a black screen showing "/dev/sda2: Recovering journal" and "/dev/sda2: clean .../... files, .../... blocks", afterwards the ubuntu logo pops up along with the white dots beneath. From than on, nothing happens, it is stuck.

What I tried/figured out (besides googling alot):
So within the grub menu I selected the recovery mode and tested some things.

E.g. I ran "fcsk":
This showed up and then the laptop was stuck (pressing enter did not help), also note the first line, that "/etc/default/rcS" was not found:
[image: fcsk]

When I enter into the root console, after some time this shows up:
[image: failed boot for /boot/efi]

Here is the output of blkid and content of /etc/fstab:
[image: fstab and blkid]

What I also tried was running "dpkg". This this showed up and it was stuck as well:
[image: dpkg]

I have no idea what to try or find out anymore sadly. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Is this a fresh install, or an upgrade? Did this ever work? Can you fully boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB? Exactly how did you do the fsck, and what command did you give it? Is your computer and older model? What processor?

Comment: It is kind of fresh, the laptop was used for some days before without problems. Maybe the laptop was closed (physically closed) during shut down and Ubuntu couldnt handle it? 
I did the "fsck" from the recovery menu. 
I cant answer right now on the exact processor type, but it is definitely an older model with a low-end intel processor, if I remember correctly. 
Booting with live USB works

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["dev/sda1: clean, ..." This message appears after I startup my laptop, then it won't continue booting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/882385/dev-sda1-clean-this-message-appears-after-i-startup-my-laptop-then-it-w)

Answer (score 1):

You may have a problem with an older computer, with an older GPU. Try this...

- boot to recovery mode
- choose root access

type:

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw /        # to remount the disk r/w

sudo pico /etc/gdm3/custom.conf   # edit this file
```

change:

```
#WaylandEnable=false
```

to:

```
WaylandEnable=false
```

Then reboot.

**Update #1:**

- boot to recovery mode
- choose root access

type:

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw /        # to remount the disk r/w

sudo cp /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.BCK # backup the file first

sudo pico /etc/fstab              # edit the file
```

change:

```
UUID=2AF3-34F1 /boot/efi vfat umask=0077 0 1
```

to:

```
UUID=2AF3-34F1 /boot/efi vfat defaults 0 1
```

reboot the computer

Comment: Thanks for your input, but sadly this did not help. Now the purple window with "Ubuntu" pops up (now weirdly even without the white dots beneath) and again, nothing happens from that point on. :(

Comment: @Corrumpo see update #1 in my answer. Report back.

Comment: I tried that.
In root access I entered "exit" afterwards and then pressed on "resume" afterwards. A warning about graphics appears (something like having to fully restart for some components to work) and afterwards I get into a console again showing "You are in emergency mode. [...] Press Enter for maintenance...". After I pressed enter, again, the computer is stuck. :(

Comment: Afterwards I started in recovery mode again and entered root access, did the mount command, checked whether the changes were saved (they were saved) and entered "systemctl reboot" to make a regular shutdown, but still not booting :( Was just thinking that a regular shutdown could help because otherwise I always needed to press and hold the power button.

Comment: The issue is likely related to that error message in my second image, right?

Comment: @Corrumpo yes, second and third images.

Comment: @Corrumpo status please

Comment: What did you change instead of backing up the file? Your last update (#1) already included the change from "umask=0077" to "defaults".

Comment: I do now try to reinstall ubuntu, but that problem might occur again. Upvote for your help. If you have further ideas, I am open for them; especially if the problem occurs again. ;(

Comment: @Corrumpo yes, the whole point of Update #1 is to change the umask. Did you make that change? After reboot, did it fix the problem?