# /dev/sda1: clean, ... blocks, system is not booted properly

Tags: 16.04, boot, nvidia

I know this question already duplicated. I check the below question and followed the answers. My problem is not solved.

Ref:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43142832/how-to-skip-dev-sda1-clean-in-booting-system
- ["dev/sda1: clean, ..." This message appears after I startup my laptop, then it won't continue booting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/882385/dev-sda1-clean-this-message-appears-after-i-startup-my-laptop-then-it-w)

The network is not connected during the boot time, so, I can't able to run apt-get update in console mode.

And, I stopped the fsck check (/etc/fstab) for the boot time.

I followed https://askubuntu.com/a/974910/268445 solution. After I purthe nvidia*, I get the https://i.stack.imgur.com/AiwJH.png error. I can't able to reinstall the nvidia lib.

Still my problem is not solved. After booting, the **/dev/sda1: clean...** error message blinked 3 times and stopped.

Is there any way to debug & resolved this problem.

Machine: Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Can't you boot in low graphics mode and then run `apt-get update`?

Comment: I tried. But, not solved.

Comment: That is not very clear. What happened when you tried to boot in low graphics mode? Did you get a prompt, or an error message?

Comment: After select the low graphics mode, again the /dev/sda1:clean error message shown.