# How to fix a corrupt Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: boot, nouveau

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04. I've just about done everything, from creating a Boot Repair CD to going to every single forum and getting ideas for how to repair it which didn't work.

```
/dev/sda1: clean, 205426/15130016 files, 2758381/60531712 blocks  
Welcome to emergency mode! After logging in type "journalctl -xb" to view   
system logs, "systemctl reboot"  to reboot, "systemctl default" or ^D to  
try again to boot into default mode.   
Give root password for maintenance  
(or press Control-D to continue): _
```

I'm able to login when I give the maintenance password but I'm not able to get to the desktop. When I use `startx`, it doesn't recognize it.

Comment: please also attach the journalctl -xb logs if possible

Comment: Status please...

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["dev/sda1: clean, ..." This message appears after I startup my laptop, then it won't continue booting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/882385/dev-sda1-clean-this-message-appears-after-i-startup-my-laptop-then-it-w)

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is with your nouveau video driver.

**Lets first check your file system for errors.**

To check the file system on your Ubuntu partition...

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery mode
- choose Root access
- at the # prompt, type `sudo fsck -f /`
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

If for some reason you can't do the above...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- open a `terminal` window
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/XXXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/XXXX` # replacing XXXX with the number you found earlier
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

**If that doesn't solve your problem**, boot to the GRUB menu, hit the <kbd>e</kbd> key, find "quiet splash" and change it to "quiet splash nomodeset", then <kbd>control</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd> to continue to boot. Reinstall your video drivers.