# No Linux-Swap listed, how do increase the disk space on already installed Ubuntu without live CD

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted, swap, disk

I have dual boot with windows and Ubuntu 18.04. I have recently run out of space and would like to increase my disk space on Ubuntu 18.04.

I have shrank my volumes on Windows system to increase some space. I have to unallocated disk space of 14GB and around 10GB, I would like to add them to the Ubuntu.

My issue is I have no linux swap showing up. When I checked on the terminal with the command,

> sudo swapon --show

```
NAME      TYPE SIZE USED PRIO
/swapfile file 1,9G   0B   -2
```

So does that mean I have a Swap but its not listed on Gparted and might be included in my extended partition which is ext4 here.

If so how do I add the unallocated disk space to my Ubuntu system ?

I'm pretty new to the Linux world , would appreciate some help from the community!

[image: Gparted]

Moved the disks as below,

[image: After Moving the disks and creating space]

When I ran to apply changes , I was greeted with the below error.

[image: Error when applying changes]

Comment: Recent versions of Ubuntu do not use a swap partition. They use a swap file called `/swapfile` by default.

Comment: @user68186 I have edited my answer, I have tried a few things and it errored out.

Comment: Best to only edit Windows NTFS partitions with Windows tools. And make sure Windows fast start up is off. You cannot from installed system modify mounted partitions, shown with tiny key icon. You do have to use a live installer. In fact you should always have two flash drives, one with Ubuntu's live installer and one with Windows Repair/recovery console. see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions The red error message on the Microsoft system reserved is ok, as it must be unformated. But the error message on the Windows partition is from fast start up.

Comment: I will try to turn off the fast startup and try again

Comment: I used a 3rd party software to change the allocated space paritions ang got into serious probs. My ubuntu couldnt recognize the boot files. I followed the instructions here to fix the issue, [Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/882385/dev-sda1-clean-this-message-appears-after-i-startup-my-laptop-then-it-w)