# /dev/sda1: clean, xxxxx files, xxxxx blocks

Tags: login, files, development, cleanup

I wanted to install Crossover application by following guidelines from [linuxhelp.com](https://www.linuxhelp.com/how-to-install-crossover-in-ubuntu) and once I got an error I ran `apt-get -f install`.

Then I shut it down and when I wanted to run on the came up and I don't know what to do.

First this error comes:

```
/dev/sda1: clean, 1374794/15630336 files, 39768980/62514432 blocks
```

[image: photo of screen showing /dev/sda1 message]

Then it says to log in. I tried to login to my account and it says it's incorrect.

[image: photo of screens showing text-based login prompt]

Is there any way to solve the problem?

Comment: First of all, the "/dev/sda1: clean" message is not an error. It is the output from fsck, which is run at boot. Fsck checks the file system, and the message you are referring to tells you that the filesystem is "clean", meaning "in good health". As for the other question, it seems like you may have removed the desktop environment, which can easily happen if you blindly run 'apt-get -f install'. Does anything happen if you hold down CTRL+ALT and then hit F7 once you're at the login prompt?

Comment: I tired but nothing happend. How can I install desktop environment without harming my files

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["dev/sda1: clean, ..." This message appears after I startup my laptop, then it won't continue booting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/882385/dev-sda1-clean-this-message-appears-after-i-startup-my-laptop-then-it-w)