# Boot stuck issue 20.04 LTS

Tags: boot, 20.04

20.04 LTS on Dell Latitude E7250
After updating to latest Ubuntu software, when I rebooted this black screen appeared.

[image]

I'm using Ubuntu standalone on my laptop. Kindly help me.
PS: I'm very new to Linux (just a month or so). Guide me in a noob friendly way.

Update:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

so my problem is solved by
["dev/sda1: clean, ..." This message appears after I startup my laptop, then it won't continue booting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/882385/dev-sda1-clean-this-message-appears-after-i-startup-my-laptop-then-it-w)

they suggested to run a command `sudo service gdm3 status` which showed gdm inactive (dead) so I gave another command `sudo service gdm3 start` and bang I'm in the system again.