# Error on boot after dev/sdb1: clean, ***/*** files, ***/*** blocks

Tags: boot, ram, bios

Have a boot error where Ubuntu fails to properly startup after giving the line:

```
dev/sdb1: clean, ***/*** files, ***/*** blocks
```

where `dev/sdb1` is my root file system. This error popped up after my computer crashed for an unknown reason about 50 boot attempts ago after running a python script. No clue why it went down on that boot and didn't check journalctl when it first occurred. My computer has persistently had the issue where in my windows OS, the system spontaneously crashes. With ubuntu, further, I have had related issues before that turned out to just be related to the nvidia graphics driver bug. Here, however, I am at a loss. I have tried the following after googling around a ton the last 3 hours:

1. Uninstall and reinstall `nvidia`-related packages;
2. Uninstall and do not reinstall `nvidia`-related packages;
3. Uninstall and reinstall `xserver-xorg-video-intel`;
4. running memtester (showed nothing informative after 5 loops and exited without error/warning/problem of note with status indicating memory health); system doesn't seem to have `memtest86+` in the grub menu as it is 64 bit and apparently it is no longer supported with UEFI and I don't have another computer on which I can create a bootable media for `memtest86`;
5. Running my Windows OS dual-booted (operates without obvious error for the 20 minutes I played around with it to double check);
6. Recovery mode in Ubuntu is functional spottily (on a few recovery attempts the system hung in the same place as a normal boot sequence, though this only happened once);
7. Ensuring that nouveau drivers are disabled by uninstalling and reinstalling nouveau, and manually setting it to mode `0`;

Thus far my efforts to fix the problem have been less-than-fruitful, so I'm at a loss. [Link to journalctl output](http://www.filedropper.com/ctl) provides the output of `journalctl --boot=-1` after my most recent boot attempt (prior to entering recovery mode via `grub` which is how I am writing this now) was to the default grub option of `ubuntu`, which hung at the line noted above, and then I pressed the power button on my desktop to reset. I really have no clue what to do with `journalctl` output, so hoping somebody can make some sense of this. My last thought that I personally have to do is reflash the BiOS, but I really don't want to do that ideally as I've never done it before, and it is very strange to me that my Windows OS and recovery mode for ubuntu are functional if there were a potential BiOS issue, which leads me to believe it is ubuntu-related. Not sure how to proceed; any help is much appreciated.

Comment: That is not an error, just a message that indicates the filesystem is clean, which is a good thing. Some hardware may be faulty, so find a way to test RAM and storage.

Comment: Yah; I know this is not an error, it is just the most recent entry on the boot screen. I tried checking RAM with `memtester`; do you think this is good enough? Or is `memtest86` really that much better? Also, what is the "best" way to test device storage? That is a good idea as my windows partition which seems to be functional is on a different storage device.

Comment: SSD comes up clean via long test from `smartctl`; HDD is not a root partition nor has any system-level data on it but that comes up clean too. `memtester` gives clean RAM as well. Any other thoughts? Or perhaps one of these utilities is no good that I used?

Comment: Here: https://askubuntu.com/q/882385/1157519

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["dev/sda1: clean, ..." This message appears after I startup my laptop, then it won't continue booting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/882385/dev-sda1-clean-this-message-appears-after-i-startup-my-laptop-then-it-w)