# Upgrading from 18.04 to 20.04, unable to boot, incorrect graphics driver being used?

Tags: boot, 18.04, upgrade, 20.04

Before the black screen with blinking cursor, I get the Ubuntu loading screen. I can use the tty terminal.

A comment under the answer here: ["dev/sda1: clean, ..." This message appears after I startup my laptop, then it won't continue booting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/882385/dev-sda1-clean-this-message-appears-after-i-startup-my-laptop-then-it-w)
Says that a similar issue is probably due to the incorrect graphics driver being used. If this is so, how do I know which is one is wrong and vise versa?

I have an Acer Spin, and it's the the one that doesn't have full bios, only uefi, so no legacy mode option and no ptt security option. It seems I'm pretty stuck.

I have Intel processor core i5, Intel graphics controller HD graphics 620 ddr4 sdram i915.

I have access to a live boot USB of Ubuntu 16.04, and it works.

Comment: [Acer Spin model identifier](https://www.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/drivers) could help you figure out the specs. The terminal way involves [lshw](https://linux.die.net/man/1/lshw) and/or [lspci](https://linux.die.net/man/8/lspci) and/or installing [mesa-utils](https://wiki.debian.org/Mesa) to find the graphics card(s) so you can identify and install the correct drivers.

Comment: I added the info.

Answer (score 0):

Because I am unable to access full bios, the solution to this issue is to install windows 8/10. However, I don't have those available, so I installed Ubuntu 16.04 from a live boot USB and removed 20.04 (plus all my files). It seems to have fixed it. I saw someone say that being able to install Ubuntu on an Acer is within itself a "miracle," so it seems drastic measures will have to be taken for Acer users who want to use Ubuntu. At least I know soon I'll have get a Dell or something, and perhaps I won't face as many issues.

Comment: We used Lubuntu for several years on a Acer Aspire 5253. It was no trouble to install. But that computer was low-spec, more like a netbook, and we moved on. It was also pre-UEFI.