# Ubuntu get stuck at "/dev/sda6: clean" message with some number on bootup. Help!

Tags: cleanup

I executed `sudo apt autoremove` in cmd and restarted the pc.

After that it gets stuck at this message

> `/dev/sda6: clean, 509610/4071424" files, 7994479/16284672 blocks`

Comment: That message is normal. Do you know what got removed?  Why did you do the autoremove?

Comment: In most cases, it is relevant to your graphics cards or their packages.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["dev/sda1: clean, ..." This message appears after I startup my laptop, then it won't continue booting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/882385/dev-sda1-clean-this-message-appears-after-i-startup-my-laptop-then-it-w)

Answer (score 1):

When you use `sudo apt autoremove` you are attempting to remove an apt package and all it's dependencies.
I would attempt pressing the `[enter]` key to try and push the OS past the block/clean also you could try to open a new terminal `ALT + F2` and login that way.

Comment: I tried Alt+F2 method but it shows " 20 updates can be inserted immediately.to see these additional updates run: apt list --upgradable" and it shows check you internet connection or proxy settings. Plz help me to get into the os

Comment: If you are allowed to type in the new terminal, make sure you get a response back from `ping google.com` to make sure you have internet access and correct dns settings. If you have internet access and dns setup correctly you can update and upgrade packages in apt with `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` this will update any new packages and upgrade them into your system, you could alternately update than look through the packages to see which you'd like to upgrade to.

Comment: I installed lubuntu and after sometimes I uninstalled it but it show in booting logo why, is that's the reason for problem

Comment: I updated and upgraded which was shown in Alt+F2 mode but still the problem exists, what to do next plz help me

Comment: So you're at an active terminal that you can now type commands into? than I don't know what your problem is now?

Comment: I'm going to also refer you to this question/answer as it pertains to a similar issue as you. https://askubuntu.com/questions/882385/dev-sda1-clean-this-message-appears-after-i-startup-my-laptop-then-it-w