# Why do I get "/dev/sda5: recovering journal" "/dev/sda5: clean..." on boot

Tags: boot

This is the message I got:

[image: photo of black screen with messages from title of question]

Why is this happening? Before this my terminal and many other apps disappeared.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["dev/sda1: clean, ..." This message appears after I startup my laptop, then it won't continue booting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/882385/dev-sda1-clean-this-message-appears-after-i-startup-my-laptop-then-it-w)

Comment: It happens because there may be problems with the HDD, or whatever storage device.

Comment: The messages you photographed were because it was a scheduled `fsck` (file system check) OR more likely, the machine was not cleanly shutdown last time, thus it was done to try and prevent data loss.  If you see this message, the usual cause was the machine was not cleanly shutdown last time (ie. power off via button, power loss or other cause). To prevent it use a command, or kernel (SysRq) key combination to tell your system to shutdown.

Comment: My Ubuntu is not opening I’am trying for an hour -@guiverc

Answer (score 2):

The short answer: Your system crashed and rebooted, but you're lucky that nothing is wrong with the files on the drive.

Comment: When this screen will go , so I could use my OS @ApolloLV

Comment: That's not something I can answer with the information you provided, as the crash cause is not shown. A lot of people appear to have issues with graphics drivers, but it might be a hardware issue as well, or something entirely different. You will have to boot a LiveUSB and then try to diagnose the issue with it. Otherwise there's nothing you can do to your machine in this state that will help.

Comment: If you've been waiting for more than a few minutes, then it won't be resolving itself and you can just shut it down.

Comment: Is there any other solution @ApolloLV

Comment: Not really. Get a Live USB and, ideally, someone with experience to help you fix it.

Comment: I think it is because of a power cut , and my PC was on inverter. @ApolloLV