# Ubuntu 20.04 stuck at "/dev/nvme0n1p5 clean. xxx/xxx files. xxx/xxx blocks" during boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 20.04

I'm using a Thinkpad X1 Yoga with dual boot Windows 10 + Ubuntu 20.04. Yesterday I installed imagick and rebooted my PC, and now I can't boot into Ubuntu because it shows a black screen with a single line `/dev/nvme0n1p5 clean. xxx/xxx files. xxx/xxx blocks` shown. I can't use ttyl (e.g. Ctrl+Alt+F1) either. These give me a completely black screen with using a typing cursor. I can boot into Windows 10 fine.

Comment: Have you tried some answers here https://askubuntu.com/questions/882385/dev-sda1-clean-this-message-appears-after-i-startup-my-laptop-then-it-w yet? I would always boot with a live CD (iso) then select "Try Ubuntu" then unmount the / and run fsck for such errors.

Comment: It seems none of the solutions in the above link work. 1. Can't switch to ttyl as stated above. 2. My laptop doesn't have an nvidia display card. 3. heynnema's solution doesn't solve my problem either. 4. I also looked into /etc/default/grub and there isn't something called "nomodeset"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is as follows (not sure what made it work exactly):

connect laptop to internet with lan cable
boot to the GRUB menu
choose Advanced Options
choose Recovery mode
choose enable Networking
choose Root access

Repeatedly try

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get update --fix-missing
```