# Boot fails and black screen error :/dev/nvme0n1p6: clean, xxxx/xxxx files , xxxx/xx blocks

Tags: boot, nvidia

My problem happens when I boot my laptop.

- **Context :**

First , I have a dual-boot Ubuntu 20.04 , Windows 10 .
Everything was working fine , but now I can't access to my Ubuntu disk , the window's one is working well .

- **The problem :**

I can't boot to Ubuntu. It shows me the following error :

```
/dev/nvme0n1p6: clean, 512216/6111232 files , xxxx/xxxxx blocks.
```

- **Fsck debug:**

`sudo fsck -f`

```
fsck de util-linux 2.34
e2fsck 1.45.5 (07-jan-2020)
/dev/nvme0n1p6 is mounted .
e2fsck: Can't continue . Aborting .
```

- I tried different things , and honestly reviewed all posts related to this ,
  ( even if connecting to my wifi from secure boot was difficult because I have a special authentification wifi ...) , I tried sudo apt-get update , I also tried to purge nvidia* packets and reinstall drivers and it didn't work , I hope you can help because it's the end of the semester and I need my Ubuntu disk for my finals , any response would be very appreciated !

Comment: Please indicate what machine you are using.

Comment: Does the laptop boot to a grub menu? And then you choose windoze or Ubuntu?

Comment: @Raffles Asus Vivobook 15 spec: i7 10gen , Nvidia

Comment: @darth_epoxy Yes , that's where I can choose to boot on Ubuntu or Windows ! And hopefully my laptop is still useable otherwise I'll be in big troubles .

Comment: OK so the message you are getting is not an error so that's good. And grub is up so that's good too. You should be able to boot via reovery mode, read the answer here https://askubuntu.com/questions/1277842/ubuntu-20-04-stuck-at-dev-nvme0n1p5-clean-xxx-xxx-files-xxx-xxx-blocks-duri

Comment: @darth_eproxy I did it by accessing commandline with ctrl alt f3 , and the update everything still not working . I coulnt do it from recover mode because I couldnt connect to my wifi from it .

Comment: @Raffles Informations like what ?

Comment: Can you beg/steal/borrow a USB dongle (modem) or will it tether to your phone? Best bet is recovery mode, connect to internet, then `sudo apt-get update` and report the result to the community.

Comment: @darth_epoxy Yes I did it but it didn't fix my problem. I also tried to purge all Nvidia, and sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall after it but I didn't work as well. This is very heart-breacking!

Comment: Did you do anything in the BIOS/UEFI just before this happened? Did you perhaps enable Windows fast boot by mistake?

Comment: @Raffles i think the Windows fast boot was enabled by default , but yes It was the case , and I disable it and reboot but I'm still stuck with the same error .

Comment: What do you see when run the following command?

`fdisk -l`

Comment: FYI:  You report "*The problem : I can't boot to Ubuntu. It shows me the following error : ..*" and show a successful `fsck` message;  the cause of that is an unclean shutdown in the prior session; thus potential issue was detected & `fsck` is run.  Solution to that is only clean shutdown (using SysRq commands rather than for example the power button you may have been using).  That is at most a symptom of a problem; the problem being user error via unclean shutdown. Next issue is you have a mounted drive you're trying to `fsck`, you need to `umount` it first - easiest via *live* media.FYI only