# Ubuntu 20.04 stuck at “/dev/nvme0n1p6 clean. xxx/xxx files. xxx/xxx blocks” during boot

Tags: boot, partitioning, mount, shutdown, disk-usage

I have shutdown Linux after using Docker, which was using all storage available (the system warned it had 0 bytes available). Now I can't boot Linux, as it shows: dev/nvme0n1p6 clean .... files. I'm using a Thinkpad x1 yoga with dual boot Win10 + Ubuntu 20.04

I've tried [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1277842/ubuntu-20-04-stuck-at-dev-nvme0n1p5-clean-xxx-xxx-files-xxx-xxx-blocks-duri), but it didn't work because I'm having trouble accessing the network.

[According to another post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1298321/boot-fails-and-black-screen-error-dev-nvme0n1p6-clean-xxxx-xxxx-files-xxxx), it seems to me that the comments suggest to unmount the problematic partition and then run fsck?

**Fsck debug: sudo fsck -f**

```
/dev/nvme0n1p6 is mounted .

e2fsck: Can't continue . Aborting .
```

**Partition info**

```
/dev/nvme0n1p6 Size  Use Avail Use% Mounted on
               11.5G 11G 0     100   /
```

Is a viable option to unmount /dev/nvme0n1p6? What to do next?

EDIT: Thanks to @David. You will need to boot from live media, and free up some space manually.

Thanks.

Comment: If you have no free space on the drive, which I suspect is the issue then fsck will not fix that. You need to boot from live media and free up some space.

Comment: @David that's it. Remember, kids, don't shut down Ubuntu 20.04 if you have 0 bytes available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your drive is full, so you need to boot from the live media and remove some junk.

First, try cleaning up the `/mnt/tmp` (assuming that's your Ubuntu partition). Then look if your home directories use too much space and do decluttering. Also try removing unused and unnecessary packages from your partiton, including any left-overs after uninstallation if any (requires chrooting to your partition in terminal).

After doing some spring cleaning, check if your NVMe drive used storage is at below 90 percent. If it's below 90 percent (below 80 is better), reboot into your Ubuntu install (finger crossed).

Comment: can you explain how to clean up /mnt/tmp. I am not able to login. I have to enter recovery mode and then what next? can you please elaborate.