# boot stuck at /dev/sda clean XXX/XXX files, XXX/XXX blocks [20.04]

Tags: boot, gdm

Been running 20.04 nicely for ~6 months. Laptop was sluggish today so did a reboot and now stuck at the titular screen.

```
/dev/sda7: clean, nnnnn/nnnnn files, nnnn/nnnnnblocks
```

Similar questions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1331344/ubuntu-20-04-stuck-at-dev-nvme0n1p6-clean-xxx-xxx-files-xxx-xxx-blocks-duri) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/882385/dev-sda1-clean-this-message-appears-after-i-startup-my-laptop-then-it-w) but solutions to those not working

(fwiw the partition is on sda7 and running `df -h` from tty2 shows 87 of 178GB are used, with 52% remaining)

I saw it suggested elsewhere that it might be to do with Gnome Display manager and `sudo systemctl status gdm.service` reports

```
Unit gdm.service could not be found.
```

running `runlevel` from tty2 gives

```
N 5
```

Comment: Can you try to install gdm?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["dev/sda1: clean, ..." This message appears after I startup my laptop, then it won't continue booting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/882385/dev-sda1-clean-this-message-appears-after-i-startup-my-laptop-then-it-w)