# Dual boot with Windows error - Intel Optane

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows, raid

After years of using Windows I decided to try out Ubuntu. I decided to start by making a dual boot. I am using Acer Predator laptop which has the Intel Optane memory.

So my Windows SSD is the Intel one and I wanted to install Ubuntu on my second SSD (Samsung, shouldn't matter). I took out the Windows SSD and left just the formatted Samsung one. Booted into Ubuntu, the install didn't work. I had to solve the RST issue that pops up during Ubuntu install. I changed the SATA mode in BIOS to AHCI (from Optane in raid). That made it work.

After installing the Ubuntu I tried booting to Windows which didn't work. I had to go back to BIOS and change the SATA mode back to Optane in raid. That made Windows boot normally but at the same time mess up Ubuntu.

I don't understand how the disk that Windows is installed on affects Ubuntu disk, as they shouldn't be tied to each other.

When I try to boot into Ubuntu I get stuck on a black screen with this text:

```
[ 0.089819] x86/cpu: SGX disabled by BIOS
[ 0.699865] Integrity: Problem loading X.509 certificate -65
[ 0.699904] Integrity: Problem loading X.509 certificate -65
Gave up waiting for root file system device. Common problems:

-Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
- Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
- Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev)

ALERT! UUID=e0414a0b-d94e-4a2f-ae62-e4e136518939 does not exist. Dropping to a shell!

BusyBox v1.30.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.30.1-6ubuntu2) built-in shell (ash)

Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs)
```

Comment: The error message means it cannot find the disk it was configured to boot from. `(initramfs)` is a prompt where you can issue some (very limited and crude) commands to troubleshoot.

Comment: You want to dual boot? Yet you removed the disk with windows on it? So how can the Ubuntu install know you want to dual boot? If the windows disk had been present you would have been asked to install ALONG SIDE windows IE dual boot.

Comment: David:
What I understood is that it is better to take the disk out for the install and then put it back in.

If I would leave the disk in, it wouldn't change anything as I still had the error while installing ubuntu that said to turn the RST off (that was essentially why I tried solving that by taking the SSD out). That is the furthest I have gone with both disks in. That would mean changing the SATA mode again and that makes the Windows not boot up. I hope that this makes sense.

Comment: You need to install AHCI support in Windows then change the drive mode to AHCI. Re-enabling Intel RST will automatically make Ubuntu unbootable.

Comment: Is there a way how to use windows with the Optane on one SSD and Linux on the other SSD?
You are right that after turning the Optane off and changing the drive mode to AHCI made both work (after some fixes to Ubuntu: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1277842/ubuntu-20-04-stuck-at-dev-nvme0n1p5-clean-xxx-xxx-files-xxx-xxx-blocks-duri)

Comment: Intel Optane - See Intel response that no performance difference between RAID & AHCI.
https://communities.intel.com/thread/121155