# Can't boot into Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, boot-repair, secure-boot

I have dual booted Ubuntu 20.04 alongside Windows 10 this morning. Everything has been fine since installation, but now after restart I can't boot into Ubuntu and this is the error message I see:
[image]

I am using HP bs-145tu laptop with Intel core-i5 8250U with 8GB RAM and no GPU.

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: Thanks for that. But, I don't know. I have to try everything from that long list of suggestions and only then will i able to tell you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["dev/sda1: clean, ..." This message appears after I startup my laptop, then it won't continue booting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/882385/dev-sda1-clean-this-message-appears-after-i-startup-my-laptop-then-it-w)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had multiple python versions installed and when trying to retain only one and remove all the remaining versions, I broke the system. And learned this the hard way that python is a dependency for lot of apps and even system too. So, in recovery mode, I did:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

and then:

```
reboot
```

Then I had no problems booting into Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

rtw_pci indicates a realtek wifi adapter, which has a lot of compatibility issues with linux. I assume you have used a bootable USB stick for installation, and if so, open it and repair the disk using GParted or Disks. Then, Please check out [this github repository](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw88) for the appropriate drivers needed, as I guess these might be causing the problem.

Comment: I can't boot into Ubuntu. How do I open  GParted or Disks.

Comment: As I mentioned in the answer, use a bootable USB stick.