# Black screen after upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04

Tags: boot, grub2, upgrade, uefi

My Ubuntu does not boot. I tried to upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04, but something happened during this process. Now it does not boot. I booted it using live USB, installed boot repair and made a check of my system: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/kKnSZGX3z2/

Then, I tried to repair boot, here is the report: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/cdMCxJXNGJ/

But after repair it is still not loading.

I tried to use this answer:

> ["dev/sda1: clean, ..." This message appears after I startup my laptop, then it won't continue booting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/882385/dev-sda1-clean-this-message-appears-after-i-startup-my-laptop-then-it-w)
> But i can't make a terminal to appear by using CTRL+ALT+F2 to F7, How
> can I fix that?

Please help me figure out what is wrong. Thank you.

Comment: "But i can't make a terminal to appear by using CTRL+ALT+F2 to F7, ", for no good reason, that has been changed. Try Ctrl-Alt-F3.

Comment: @GyroGearloose This does not helped

Comment: What does "Ctrl-Alt-F3" do on your box? No reaction at all. or something different?

Comment: No reaction at all

Comment: When i hit power off, i do see ubuntu screen when it powers off,

Comment: Do you have a second box (or can bowwow it from a friend) to log in from remote to see what's going on?

Comment: I just have a laptop running on Windows, and both my computers connects wireless to modem.

Comment: So if you can remember or guess the ip of your sick box, you can try to ssh <ip>, or previously ping <ip>. I wil delete much of the comments which are growing into a discussion.

Comment: @GyroGearloose I was able to get in to TTY using ALT+CTRL+F3, and run sudo dpkg --configure -a, which fixed my problem. Thank you for your help.

Comment: If you think this could be helpful to others, you can answer your own question, for the benefit of others having similar problems.