# dev/sda1: clean, 552599/6111232 files, 7119295/24414464 blocks

Tags: grub2, nvidia, 20.04, startup

basically what happened that my laptop was not showing grub menu when it starting so i changed the file /etc/default/grub after following some youtube videos and it did work but after doing this,
**dev/sda1: clean, 552599/6111232 files, 7119295/24414464 blocks**

this line is also appearing while starting up.

Note: uninstalled nvidia drivers..but didn't work

Comment: Not an error just an information message just ignore. Do not know why you thought it was the video drivers causing it noting in your question that gives a hint they did.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["dev/sda1: clean, ..." This message appears after I startup my laptop, then it won't continue booting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/882385/dev-sda1-clean-this-message-appears-after-i-startup-my-laptop-then-it-w)