# I can not open Ubuntu

Tags: password-recovery, passwd

I am using Ubuntu 20.4 LTS. After changing my password with s`udo passwd username`, this code and got problem. I reboot to test the password but it stuck with:

```
sda6: clean xx/xx file, xxx/xx block.
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["dev/sda1: clean, ..." This message appears after I startup my laptop, then it won't continue booting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/882385/dev-sda1-clean-this-message-appears-after-i-startup-my-laptop-then-it-w) and if that doesn't work try [How do I reset a lost administrative password?](https://askubuntu.com/q/24006/)

Comment: There is no version 20.4 do you mean 20.04?