# "/dev/nume0nlp7: clean, 206252/1222992 files, 3661566/4882432 blocks" appears when I boot Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 20.04

When I boot Ubuntu after choosing the option in GRUB menu, after a minute, I get this error:

```
/dev/nume0nlp7: clean, 206252/1222992 files, 3661566/4882432 blocks
```

I tried advanced options for Ubuntu  to use recovery mode but I encountered with different and unfamiliar options. I don't know which one is the right.

- ubuntu, with linux 5.8.0-45- generic
- ubuntu, with linux 5.8.0-45- generic (recovery mode)
- ubuntu, with linux 5.6.0-1050-oem generic
- ubuntu, with linux 5.6.0-1050-oem generic (recovery mode)

Comment: Hi and welcome. What happens after the error? Does it just stay like that? If you want recovery mode choose 5.8 recovery mode to recover the latest kernel.

Comment: I'd choose the `5.6.0-1050-oem` kernel initially as that probably shipped with your device. Does that boot okay?

Comment: @David yeah the screen freezed on that error 
btw i used recovery mode and now it's fine
tnx

Comment: @popey yeah i did the same and it was ok
tnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i used ubuntu, with linux 5.6.0-1050-oem generic (recovery mode)
and i used this command and everything is fine now
`sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop`

actually i dont know what really happend so i would be glad if someone could explain what does the command do and why did this happend?

Answer (score 0):

I'm very sorry for posting this as the answer. I don't have 50 reputation yet to comment, but this is definitely just a comment.
The row you described above is not an error. It's just an info message, that at least on my laptop doesn't make any sense. See the post on askubuntu below for explanation of this message (and maybe solution, because your post looks like duplicate or very related). Have you tried to wait at least 5-10 minutes? If nothing changes, then i recommend to look into boot log to determine the real error.

["dev/sda1: clean, ..." This message appears after I startup my laptop, then it won't continue booting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/882385/dev-sda1-clean-this-message-appears-after-i-startup-my-laptop-then-it-w)