# booting error, I am stuck on a black screen reading "/dev/sdb2: clean, ******/****** files, *******/******** blocks". How can I get back into my PC?

Tags: graphics, login, boot-repair, ubuntu-drivers

I am stuck on /dev/sdb2: clean, ******/****** files, *******/******** blocks view when I turn on my computer. I have read elsewhere to ctrl+alt+f2 or ctrl+alt+f3 to get around this and deal with what it likely a graphics card issue, but this does not work for me.

Perhaps notably, the last time i used it, it said that the file space was low. Does anyone know what options I have to get back into my computer?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["dev/sda1: clean, ..." This message appears after I startup my laptop, then it won't continue booting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/882385/dev-sda1-clean-this-message-appears-after-i-startup-my-laptop-then-it-w)

Answer (score 0):

In the event your disk space is low:

1. Grab a Live disk
2. Grab an external storage media or a new internal drive

   >If using a new internal disk, connect this disk while device is not connected to power and do not disconnect old disk from the machine just yet
3. Boot into the Live disk
4. Use GParted to format new media

   >Ensure you have selected the correct media before formatting

   >Please refer to Documentation as to which format is best for your system
5. Select files under /home/user/$**YOU** to be transferred to new media

!!>> If you do decide to just swap to a larger disk, you can 1-4. to format the new storage media, and then simply move the files using the `mv` command. You may find the documentation for the `mv` command by typing `mv man` into the Terminal.