# Ubuntu 20.04 boots to black screen which says /dev/nv*******: clean, 508***/650**** files, 247*****/260******* blocks

Tags: boot, 20.04, filesystem, filemanager, ext4

Other times after I reboot this line is prefaced by `/dev/nv*******: recovering journal`

And sometime there's also a couple lines saying `/dev/nv*******: clearing orphaned inode 406**** (uid=125, gid=130, mode=0100664)`

If I boot in recovery mode I can get into a GNOME desktop, but it looks different from my usual one, I get a message saying my disk is out of space, and the desktop freezes. I booted into a terminal and cleared my Trash as the message suggested, but then booting back into that desktop it was still frozen and reported only have 500+ mb of free disk space. Based on what I know I have on this machine I should still have dozens of free gigs of space (or about half the total partition).

Before all this happened I was moving a few gigabytes worth of 2 or 3 mb photos and the GUI file manager in my GNOME desktop looked frozen. So I decided to reboot ignoring the warnings that Files was still doing work.

Based on my limited understanding of EXT4, I'm guessing that Files really was doing work and by booting in the middle of it, I left my file system in an inconsistent state. So it's trying to recover a consistent state from the journal.

What I find weird it that I left my machine on overnight just showing that one line and in the morning it was still stuck on `/dev/nv*******: clean, 508***/650**** files, 247*****/260******* blocks`

So my questions are

1. Did I screw up my file system by trying to move too many files at once or just by booting in the middle?
2. Do I have to do anything to fix it or can I just wait for it to recover from the journal?
3. If I have to fix it, how and is there a way to do so without wiping that partition and starting over?

(I'm confident it's not a hardware issue since the Windows half of the computer is working. In fact it's the partition I'm writing from now.)

Answer (score 1):

To my great surprise, `df -h` showed me that my disk usage on my Ubuntu partition was 100%. I had assumed that almost all of my disk usage would be from my *home* directory. But it turns out that *var* and *snap* are quite large as well.

Solution: I booted into recovery mode from the GRUB menu and deleted some files. Then my system was able to boot up as normal.

This thread was particularly helpful in troubleshooting.  ["dev/sda1: clean, ..." This message appears after I startup my laptop, then it won't continue booting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/882385/dev-sda1-clean-this-message-appears-after-i-startup-my-laptop-then-it-w)