# "/dev/sdb5: clean,..." This message appears after I startup my laptop, then it won't continue booting

Tags: boot, dual-boot, boot-repair

After rebooting my Ubuntu, I get this message:

```
dev/sdbf5: clean, 228978/2564096 files, 2910015/10240000 blocks
```

I'm running dual boot on my machine (win10, Ubuntu) win10 is working fine, but now I have no idea why I'm getting this

Comment: When starting up, hold the Shift key to get to the GRUB bootloader menu. Select your Ubuntu entry using the arrow keys and press E. Can you use the arrow keys, and replace `quiet splash` with `nomodeset`, then press Ctrl and X at the same time to boot, and post the output here please?

Comment: now, Dell logo appears only

Comment: Can you add `earlyprintk=efi video=efifb` to my original comment and try again?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["dev/sda1: clean, ..." This message appears after I startup my laptop, then it won't continue booting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/882385/dev-sda1-clean-this-message-appears-after-i-startup-my-laptop-then-it-w)