# Entering password doesn't do anything

Tags: boot, nvidia, updates, password

I have a desktop running Ubuntu 20.04.  I can start the computer and I am prompted for my password but when I enter the password nothing happens. My password has not changed.  I do not get an 'incorrect password' message, the computer just goes back to the screen where I need to enter a password. I cannot get past this phase.

[Recently I did get a message like this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/882385/dev-sda1-clean-this-message-appears-after-i-startup-my-laptop-then-it-w). Thinking that I had a graphics driver problem I entered the computer using the boot menu, got to a prompt and purged and reinstalled nvidia drivers.  I do not know if all of this is related but I did do an update (as prompted to do) before all of this started.

How do I get logged into my computer?

Comment: This is called a "login loop" and it sounds like you caused the problem when you "fixed" the other one. FYI, the original issue you tried to fix is a non-issue if the system continued to boot. I recommend repeating your process to drop to a root shell prompt and revert the changes that you made

Comment: There are many reasons for a "login loop", I'd agree most with what Nmath has already suggested; however in my own circumstances (using a small disk size) I find lack of space in $HOME my most common cause... which can be detected & correct via logging via text terminal & verifying space exists (esp. in $HOME).. Adding packages will use more disk space so if $HOME isn't on a separate partition it may have created your space issue...

Comment: @guiverc, Ah, I did try to download a massive file.  That download failed when I got a error for no memory left.  Are you suggesting that I remove files from my home directory?

Comment: Yes, $HOME is shorthand for /home/$USER (ie. /home/guiverc for me) or your user directory (you can `echo $HOME` to confirm); if insufficient space exists there, a GUI login will fail & user is returned to greeter (DM login prompt) without error message; ie. login loop. Text logins don't require creation of gui-workfiles so will succeed; allowing you to use commands to explore the issue & correct (*erase files to create space*) allowing a GUI login to work.  Alternatively you could do it from *live* media (if you needed to use a GUI).