# YouTube videos on Chrome are slow to start

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, internet, video, youtube

I am using Ubuntu 20.04.

I just started to have a strange problem, every time I play a youtube video it has like 10 seconds of the loading screen (where the loading animation plays) and then it starts playing the video. On firefox youtube works fine, no delay in starting the video, so I don't think there is an internet problem. Also, on Chrome, Twitch or any other streaming websites work fine.

Something else that I have noticed is that if I wait for some time, the videos start playing normally (so no more delay at the beginning), but when I restart the browser the problem just reapers.

I have reinstalled the browser but no luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: What this has to do with Ubuntu ? This is a ram issue , chrome takes more time and ram to start , maybe there is some sort of power saver ? Why don't you see videos in firefox ?

Comment: Watching videos on FIrefox is not the point. It is not a RAM issue as Chrome works smoothly and it did long before this started happening. I thought this was a Ubuntu issue because it started happening after I had this type of error (https://askubuntu.com/questions/882385/dev-sda1-clean-this-message-appears-after-i-startup-my-laptop-then-it-w). Anyway, I looked some more into it and I think it is related to the configuration of Chrome because when I delete it, it starts working smoothly but then the problem reappears.

Comment: And also I noticed that YouTube on Chrome had some problems on Ubuntu, from other threads, so I thought this may be something like that.