# Booting problem Ubuntu 20.04 lts

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04

I have a problem booting to my graphical desktop on Ubuntu 20.04 lts, and it shows the message below.
My computer configuration is:
Processeur  Core i3-6006U 2.00 GHz
Mémoire Cache 4 Go
Graphic card Intel HD
No Video memory
And i have a windows 10 on the other boot and it's booting normally.

> /dev/sda6: clean, 92634/2207520 files, 8397675/8828416 blocks

Comment: @ChanganAuto i just made the edit, i understand what you have said and tbh i can't agree more so if you can help, thanks

Comment: Nothing stands out, your hardware should "just work". If you're dual-booting then make sure you disable the Windows' Fast Startup feature and shutdown. Try booting Ubuntu again and if the problem persists do CTRL+ALT+F3, login and do a full update: `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade`.

Comment: I already disabled Windows fast startup so, from my first installation i have the window to choose btw my boots

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["dev/sda1: clean, ..." This message appears after I startup my laptop, then it won't continue booting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/882385/dev-sda1-clean-this-message-appears-after-i-startup-my-laptop-then-it-w)

Comment: Not at all, i can't get to my Desktop