# Unable to login or reboot after I made computer disk read only and logged out of the dystem

Tags: boot, command-line, 20.04, login, read-only

I made the computer disk read only by mistake and after that I logged off from the Ubuntu and switched off my system. When I started my system then it is unable to restart or reboot. Clicked <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> but it is only showing

```
dev/sda6: recovering journal

dev/sda6: clean, 242560/1187840 files, 3331370/4742144 blocks
```

I'm unable to do login or anything after this.
System is also not going to bios mode and also unable to re-install the Linux via flash driver as not getting reboot options. Can't do anything after this:

[image: Screen photo]

Comment: When you start your computer , press F2, Shift , Escape several times. This may allow you to enter to BIOS/UEFI and boot from thumb drive.

Comment: What specifically did you do to make the disk read-only?

Comment: I used the following command in my main computer directory sudo chown -R username /

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["dev/sda1: clean, ..." This message appears after I startup my laptop, then it won't continue booting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/882385/dev-sda1-clean-this-message-appears-after-i-startup-my-laptop-then-it-w)

Comment: I'm unable to interact with my system after the error. So unable to purge nvidia or do anything. Also, tried with SysRq reboot (Alt+SysRq+b) but that also did not work.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of in your case would be to use a different computer to install a live-boot operating system on an external hard drive. Then, plug that drive into the machine you're having issues with. Since the main disk is read-only, the PC should automatically default to the next available option for re-boot, which would be external drives.

Comment: I have a live usb drive but still not getting any reboot option.

Comment: If what I wrote works, you would have to use an external disk drive (one of the large ones that hold somewhere around 220 GB) that is readable and re-writeable, not just bootable drive like a USB) Please note that I have never tried to do this before, so unless you have an external hard disk in your possession, don't spend the money purchasing one.