# Is there a easy way to install basic software like Terminal, Software Center or settings?

Tags: apt, software-installation, uninstall, crash

I ran two times into the same Problem. I execute the command apt remove python, then the system crashes and i run into following problem: ["dev/sda1: clean, ..." This message appears after I startup my laptop, then it won't continue booting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/882385/dev-sda1-clean-this-message-appears-after-i-startup-my-laptop-then-it-w)

reinstalling video driver and i get back into my system with all the basic applications like firefox, terminal/shell (ctrl + alt + t doesn't work as well) missing. They are still installed tho. the Terminal for example works in my IDE and if i reinstall firefox it says it doesn't have to install anything. It just creates a link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are removing python, you are removing most of the graphical interface. The Ubuntu system strongly depends on python. Therefore, do not change the default Python install.

The easy way to install the minimum set of components needed for a functional Ubuntu desktop is to install the metapackage `ubuntu-desktop-minimal`.

Comment: Ouf yeah now i understand why everyting went to hell :D Thank you! Windows users just can't handle the power...

Comment: @lehp When removing a package, all packages depending on it are going to be removed as well. By default, in such a situation, the `apt` command asks for confirmation and shows what's going to be removed alongside. Always check that before confirming !

Comment: @NovHak thanks for your advise. Does this consider that a package might be used by another package? So when package x is used by z and y, when i delete package z will it realise that it shouldn't delete x because y is still depending on it? And when i use several package managers like brew apt and snap will it duplicate already installed packages because those package managers don't communicate with each other or is it obvious to all of them which software is installed?

Comment: @lehp Yes, x won't be removed. Regarding the simultaneous use of different package managers, this is a complicated matter, especially considering that snaps don't really have a dependency system, as each snap is supposed to be self-contained to a large extent. There are some very Canonical-specific takes on the subject such as a core snap, and software stacks such as Gnome 3 stack snaps, but since there is no formal dependency enforcement, I guess it's best to check its use before removing a snap... but fundamentally, package managers don't have any knowledge of each other.

Comment: That being said, on Ubuntu, no apt packages will depend on a snap.