# Computer won’t boot,”/dev/sda6: clean”

Tags: boot

Whenever I start my computer,what you see above appears,and it won’t boot further,I can’t go into bios nor grub menu.Is this because I ran out of memory?Do I need to factory reset?Any help would be appreciated.[This is what I see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4C37.jpg)

Transcription:/dev/sda6: clean, 447748/1921360 files, 7298509/7680000 blocks

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["dev/sda1: clean, ..." This message appears after I startup my laptop, then it won't continue booting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/882385/dev-sda1-clean-this-message-appears-after-i-startup-my-laptop-then-it-w)

Comment: That it says clean is a good thing. It used to be that on reboot it would auto run fsck every 40 or 60 reboots. Now file system reports errors and it only needs fsck if not clean. But then you have some other boot error. Post link to report in your question above. Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Bootinfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.Lets see details, use ppa version with your USB installer (2nd option) , not Boot-Repair ISO (ISO not updated as frequently as download from ppa).
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair