# Ubuntu Starting problem

Tags: login, files, password, icons, development

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 version and when I start my pc it says like dev/sda nnn file/ nnn blocks and then it goes to login page without any ubuntu background (black) like

```
       Welcome to ..........
```

Login :

Password: ...............(It doesn't show the password)

After entering the correct username and the password it takes me to the ubuntu home windows but it does not show the file icons on the desktop (Empty desktop) also wifi connection, battery,windows icons are changed from the previous one.

Please help help me

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["dev/sda1: clean, ..." This message appears after I startup my laptop, then it won't continue booting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/882385/dev-sda1-clean-this-message-appears-after-i-startup-my-laptop-then-it-w)