# Got "dev/sda3: clean" message, then it got stuck there, and won't boot further

Tags: boot, 20.04, fsck, troubleshooting

I have installed Ubuntu 20.04. Yesterday when I tried to boot my system I got an `/dev/sda3: clean ....` message.

It seems to check the file system but the numbers didn't change. I waited for it to complete but continued until today. I tried to boot through safe mode, but had no success. what should I do to boot it successfully?

[image]

Comment: Sounds to me like a failing or failed hard drive. You can possibly boot installation media to run a live session to access the file system. Keep in mind that if the hard drive is failing, any further actions can decrease the likelihood that you will be able to retrieve any data

Comment: Status please...

Comment: @Nmath thanks for notifying me regarding failing of the hard drive.

Comment: @heynnema Successfully booted, followed step - reinstall drivers and then reinstall display manager (sudo apt install gdm3). I don't know which step solved my issue.

Followed the steps from https://askubuntu.com/questions/882385/dev-sda1-clean-this-message-appears-after-i-startup-my-laptop-then-it-w

Comment: @AbindraRajDangol That wouldn't fix the fsck problem. Edit your question and show me a screenshot of the `Disks` application **SMART Data & Tests** data window. Enlarge the window to capture all of the data you see there. Also, did you do the manual fsck from my answer?

Comment: Status please...

Comment: @heynnema I changed the question. I guess the issue in fsck is not what I had encountered. I tried the suggested steps but it didn't show any error.

Comment: here's the screenshot of SMART Data & Tests - https://postimg.cc/crPfPPm9

Comment: Do Update #1 in my answer. Report back. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Answer (score 2):

That may be a bug in Ubuntu 20.04, or a failing disk drive.

Try this manual fsck first. It should only take a minute or two.

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB in “Try Ubuntu” mode
- open a `terminal` window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/sdXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdXX`, replacing `sdXX` with the number you found earlier
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

**Update #1:**

Temporarily try booting with **nomodeset**...

- boot to the GRUB menu
- select the desired boot, probably "Ubuntu", probably already selected
- hit the "e" key to enter edit mode
- find "quiet splash"
- change it to "quiet splash nomodeset"
- hit control-x or F10 to continue booting
- if it boots, screen resolution may be off
- start **Additional Drivers**, take a screenshot, edit it into your question
- report back

Comment: thanks for your time and concern, I followed step 2 but it again shows - dev/sda3: clean, ............


I did some research over the issue and found that lots of people had faced same issue. there were different solutions. but i followed following steps and now my computer is working fine.

login through TTY3

Comment: Here is the steps i followed:
login through TTY3 and then followed these - sudo apt-get purge nvidia*

sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall  and finally reinstall display manager - sudo apt install gdm3

Answer (score 0):

Here is the steps I followed:

1. login through TTY3
2. `sudo apt-get purge nvidia*`
3. `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`
4. reinstall display manager, `sudo apt install gdm3`

This post helped me: ["dev/sda1: clean, ..." This message appears after I startup my laptop, then it won't continue booting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/882385/dev-sda1-clean-this-message-appears-after-i-startup-my-laptop-then-it-w)

Comment: You can accept your own answer instead of putting [solved] in the title :-)

Comment: @LorenzKeel thanks for reminder.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be a bug

In my case, it's because I disable the GUI last time before I shutdown my laptop (`sudo systemctl stop gdm`)

I can still login through TTY with ctrl+alt+f1