# Nouveau: unknown chipset

Tags: dual-boot, startup

I just installed Ubuntu dual booting with Windows 11 on my newly acquired PC, the installation went good, but after restarting the booting got stuck at this screen.

[image]

I have tried a multitude of things, including [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/882385/dev-sda1-clean-this-message-appears-after-i-startup-my-laptop-then-it-w) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1391967/got-dev-sda3-clean-message-then-it-got-stuck-there-and-wont-boot-further), but nothing worked.

I managed to find a workaround by entering recovering mode and only resuming to normal boot I was finally able to access the OS, but it gets annoying having to enter recovering mode every time I want to access Ubuntu.

This is the system summary from the recovery mode. As you can see I have sufficient space in every partition.

[image: This]

What should I do to boot it successfully?

I installed the 22.04.4. I checked only the box for downloading updates and not to install third-party software during the installation process.

Comment: I'm sorry, I edited the post.

Comment: What brand/model system? And what video card/chip? If nVidia you need to 9install the optional third party drivers to get correct nVidia driver. Some like HP need you to change boot order in UEFI settings. Some like Acer require you to set "trust" on the Ubuntu boot entry in UEFI settings.

Comment: The mobo is MSI and the GPU is Nvidia. I will look into this, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED! This is the solution that worked for me, I'll leave it in case anyone has this problem again:

1. In the stuck screen, first get into TTY with `CTRL + ALT + F2-7`.
2. Check if your GPU is displayed in `sudo lshw -c display`.
3. If the field `configuration` looks like `configuration: latency=0`, without any driver displayed, use the command `sudo apt install linux-modules-nvidia-525-$(uname -r)` to install the driver and then the desktop should be displayed. If not, try to `sudo reboot`. Of course, you can use any version of the driver compatible with your GPU, the version 525 worked for me.

Comment: Glad you got it working. The actual message of concern is the one about nouveau not working with your chipset. (Nouveau is the generic nvidia driver) The message you used as a title is a normal advisory message, not an error. Consider changing the title of your question to the nouveau error message to help future searchers, since it only appears in an image, which cannot be searched.

Comment: If you change or install wrong nVidia driver, you must purge old one before installing new or you get conflicts. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1478024/how-do-i-install-an-arbitrary-proprietary-nvidia-gpu-driver-on-ubuntu-studio-22