# “/dev/sda6: clean, files, blocks” message appears and it won’t continue booting

Tags: boot, apt, partitioning, nvidia, slim

I've come to ask for your help because I've managed to make my linux session inaccessible and I don't really know the extent of the damage.

Currently when I want to start the Ubuntu session the following message appears then nothing happens:

```
/dev/sda6: clean, 293099/3055616 files, 5009083/12207104 blocks
```

Here is the course of events:

I have installed slime:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install slim
```

I wanted to uninstall it
I used the command:

```
sudo apt-get remove slim
```

Then:

```
sudo apt-get purge slim
```

When restarting the session the message appeared

```
/dev/sda6: clean, 293099/3055616 files, 5009083/12207104 blocks
```

I found a similar problem on the internet which was solved by

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

I performed its actions but the problem was not solved so I'm afraid I made the situation worse. So I stop experimenting and come to ask your opinion. I'm still new to Linux but I'm aware that my approach was not very smart. I was in a hurry and I should have stopped in time.

I would be very happy to have a diagnosis of what is happening and of course a solution if it exists. Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["dev/sda1: clean, ..." This message appears after I startup my laptop, then it won't continue booting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/882385/dev-sda1-clean-this-message-appears-after-i-startup-my-laptop-then-it-w)

Comment: I think if there was an unclean poweroff. Then your pc is cleaning and you ought to wait until starts. I think it could happen if for example if pc is shut down by pressing the power button continuously. Is it possible that you have lost data? I am also new. Could you describe more?