# Cannot enter in Ubuntu 20.04 after uninstalling `libusb`

Tags: boot, 20.04, grub2

I accidentally uninstalled `libusb` from Ubuntu 20.04. The moment I uninstalled it the screen went black.

So, I shut the laptop down using the power button and reopened it. After selecting *Ubuntu* from the GRUB boot loader (I dual boot Ubuntu with Windows), I am stuck here:

[image: stuck screen after GRUB]

By pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> I opened the terminal and tried to reinstall `libusb` using `sudo apt install libusb` and then `sudo apt install libusb-1.0-0`, but gave me a *cannot find package* type error.

Comment: If the Bluetooth device is a USB remove it and reboot.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["dev/sda1: clean, ..." This message appears after I startup my laptop, then it won't continue booting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/882385/dev-sda1-clean-this-message-appears-after-i-startup-my-laptop-then-it-w)

Answer (score 0):

I did this to get back into working order:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall gnome gdm3 ubuntu-desktop
```