# Failed to start Process error reports

Tags: boot

I am getting following error `Failed to start Process error reports when automatic reporting is enabled`

And screen stuck here, any solution with live Ubuntu usb or anything else?

```
/dev/sda5: clean, 2025929/15564800 files, 40973826/62251776 blocks [FAILED] Failed to start Process error reports when automatic reporting is enabled.

[FAILED] Failed to start crash report submission daemon.

[FAILED] Failed to start MySQL Community Server.

[FAILED] Failed to start Process error reports when automatic reporting is enabled.

[FAILED] Failed to start crash report submission daemon.

[FAILED] Failed to start Process error reports when automatic reporting is enabled.

[FAILED] Failed to start MySQL Community Server.

[FAILED] Failed to start MySQL Community Server.

[FAILED] Failed to start Service for snap application anbox.container-manager.

[FAILED] Failed to start Service for snap application docker.dockerd.

[FAILED] Failed to start Systen Logging Service.

[FAILED] Failed to start D-Bus Systen Message Bus.

[FAILED] Failed to start D-Bus Systen Message Bus.
```

Comment: Please do not show pictures of text simply type that single .line message into the body of the question. What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: I am using 21.04

Comment: Ubuntu 21.04 will no longer receive any updates, starting January 20th 2022 it is now EOL and off topic sorry.

Comment: now I cannot do any thing? or I need to move on 21.10?

Comment: 21.10 goes EOL in July this year so that would not be my choice. 21.04 LTS or in a few weeks {no exact date yet) you have 22.04 LTS

Comment: Okay, thanks for your time

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["dev/sda1: clean, ..." This message appears after I startup my laptop, then it won't continue booting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/882385/dev-sda1-clean-this-message-appears-after-i-startup-my-laptop-then-it-w)

Answer (score 1):

Disabling the apport service did it for me on Ubuntu 22.10:

```
- sudo systemctl disable apport.service
```

But given all the other errors that you have disabling this has nothing to do with the root cause of your problem.  Go into /var/log (and also try sudo dmesg) and see what additional information is there to debug your issue.