# Problem with Network card: "No Wi-Fi Adapter found", and inability to connect to the internet via Ethernet, usb tethering or bluetooth

Tags: networking, drivers, bluetooth, internet

After solving the problem of the link that I have attached[1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/882385/dev-sda1-clean-this-message-appears-after-i-startup-my-laptop-then-it-w), my ubuntu 20.04.4 partition cannot connect to the network: in the wifi settings there is only the writing "No Adapter wi-fi", it does not detect the ethernet connection, such as the phone's thatering, and there is not even the possibility of connecting the settings bluetooth (and I couldn't even reinstall the graphics card).

Believing that the problem is the lack of network drivers, given the impossibility of connecting to the network, I tried to download the drivers from the bootable stick from which I downloaded my version of ubuntu, but the attempts made so far have not gone successful I believe due to my unfamiliarity with ubuntu.

I share some of the information useful to my problem:

```
 uname -a

Linux damiano-Inspiron 5.13.0-39-generic #44~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Mar 24 16:43:35 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

;

```
sudo lshw -C network


*-network UNCLAIMED       
   description: Network controller
   product: Wireless-AC 9462
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 14.3
   bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
   version: 00
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: iomemory:600-5ff memory:600111c000-600111ffffenter code here
```

;

```
lspci -knn | grep -A 2 -i net

libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:656 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nvidia-nouveau.conf line 2: ignoring bad line starting with 'option'
00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9462 [8086:02f0]
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9462 [8086:4234]
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Serial IO I2C Host Controller [8086:02e8]enter code here
```

Edit also:

```
cat /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nvidia-nouveau.conf 
blacklist nouveau
option nouveau modest=0
```

And

```
sudo modprobe iwlwifi
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:656 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nvidia-nouveau.conf line 2: ignoring bad line starting with 'option'
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:838 kmod_module_insert_module() could not find module by name='iwlwifi'
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'iwlwifi': Unknown symbol in module, or unknown parameter (see dmesg)
```

Edit2:

After commenting the line option nouveau modest=0

```
Sudo dmesg | grep iwl
```

I don't have answer anything.

```
sudo dpkg -s linux-modules-extra-5.13.0-39-generic | grep Status 
dpkg-query: the package "linux-modules-extra-5.13.0-39-generic" is not installed and no information is available 
Use "dpkg - - info (=" dpkg-deb - - info") to examime the archives
```

thank you in advance for your attention.

Comment: Let's try to fix the libkmod issue first. Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `cat /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nvidia-nouveau.conf` and also: `sudo modprobe iwlwifi` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

Comment: In your file `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nvidia-nouveau.conf ` the setting of an option is ineffective as the driver *nouveau* is blacklisted and therefore prevented from loading. Please comment out the 'option' line with #.Also, please edit your question to show: `sudo dmesg | grep iwl` and also: `sudo dpkg -s linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r) | grep Status`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package linux-modules-extra provides, among many other things, the required driver *iwlwifi*. Please download this file on some other computer and transfer it with a USB key or similar to the desktop of this Ubuntu computer.

[http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-hwe-5.13/linux-modules-extra-5.13.0-39-generic_5.13.0-39.44~20.04.1_amd64.deb](http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-hwe-5.13/linux-modules-extra-5.13.0-39-generic_5.13.0-39.44%7E20.04.1_amd64.deb)

Install it with:

```
cd ~/Desktop
sudo dpkg -i linux*.deb
```

Reboot.

Comment: Thank you very much, all network settings are restarted after performing the steps you suggested to me.

I’m trying to ask you now that the computer is working again, to clean it from my previous attempts to fix the problem, such as installing the wrong packages and the red icon on my panel in the top right, how can I proceed?

Comment: Please explain the red icon. Can you find out more about it it you click on it? Hover?