# Ubuntu 22.04 not booting

Tags: boot

I had 20.04 and upgraded to 22.04.
After installing, upon start, it opens the GRUB, I select Ubuntu normally, then it shows the following message (picture), the dash blinks for a few seconds, it freezes, then after a while the computer shuts down.
Any ideas on why is this happening and how to fix it?
[image]
Notebook Samsung 700z Intel Core i5

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["dev/sda1: clean, ..." This message appears after I startup my laptop, then it won't continue booting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/882385/dev-sda1-clean-this-message-appears-after-i-startup-my-laptop-then-it-w)

Comment: @Pilot: The link you proposed has 25 answers, which answer do you recommend to fix the OP's problem? Or should they start at the top and work there way down?