# SGX disabled by BIOS ? Can't access terminal

Tags: boot, command-line, bios, sgx

Noob here, bear with me.

I updated my Ubuntu version a couple of days ago, then got a "critical error - immediate abort" when typing in my password.

Upon booting I notice this message appears on the terminal before forcing me into the login screen:

[0.120856] x86/cpu: SGX disabled by BIOS.
/dev/nvme0n1p2: clean, 516689/15597568 files, 4421 1058/62383360 blocks

It won't let me stay in the terminal...

Halp

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["dev/sda1: clean, ..." This message appears after I startup my laptop, then it won't continue booting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/882385/dev-sda1-clean-this-message-appears-after-i-startup-my-laptop-then-it-w)