# How to make correct partition for custom bootable drive

Tags: partitioning

Error comes when making custom root file system.I install Ubuntu 20.04 on pen-drive(32gb). after installation two partition are created.First partition for boot that is EFF file System and second partition root filesystem. We taken another pen-drive and create two partition that is First partition is EFI filesystem and second is root filesystem. For second partition we make same UUID as installed install USB pen-drive. after booting in second pen-drive be get below error.

/dev/sdc2:recovering journal

/dev/sdc2: clean 336824/1847776 files, 4534330/7379456 blocks.

[FAILED] Failed to mount unit for gnome-3-38-2004,revision 99,

[FAILED] Failed to mount unit for gnome-3-38-2004, revision 87.

I also checked in boot for grub.cfg file for change UUID for same copy of root file system did not work.
I also try installed Ubuntu pen-drive remove all file and folding using rm and again copy with cp -ax it will work. but taken blank pen-drive boot is work and root file system is not working.Please guide us.

Thanks and regarding

```
 ajay
```

Comment: It's unclear exactly what you did for the 2nd pen drive and why. If you want a clone of the working one then cloning tools can and should be used.

Comment: We want to make custom root file system so instead to cloning we just copy the contain of root file system on second pen-drive but issue facing in 2nd pen-drive for partition creation? how to create correct partition.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["dev/sda1: clean, ..." This message appears after I startup my laptop, then it won't continue booting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/882385/dev-sda1-clean-this-message-appears-after-i-startup-my-laptop-then-it-w)

Comment: There is no solution for my question.