# Emergency mode on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: boot

1.When Ubuntu starts, emergency mode starts. I am new to Linux, so please help and write the steps to be performed in detail.
[Emergency mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pFJx7.jpg)

Comment: All options are on your screen.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["dev/sda1: clean, ..." This message appears after I startup my laptop, then it won't continue booting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/882385/dev-sda1-clean-this-message-appears-after-i-startup-my-laptop-then-it-w)