# "dev/sda3: clean, files" to black screen

Tags: boot

I have a fresh PC with an empty hard drive that I am attempting to install Ubuntu 20.04 to. After successfully installing the minimal version of Ubuntu, and removing the installation medium to reboot, the PC says "dev/sda3: clean, " and then a number of files and blocks.

After that, the PC immediately black screens and doesn't continue. I have attempted to reinstall Ubuntu 3 times and the same thing occurs each time.

Things to note: this PC has an Nvidia nvs 315 and a 1tb harddrive

I had to run the installer in graphics safe mode as it would not run otherwise

If I boot my Ubuntu installation using nomodeset, the "dev/sda3: clean, " the screen flashes over and over again

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["dev/sda1: clean, ..." This message appears after I startup my laptop, then it won't continue booting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/882385/dev-sda1-clean-this-message-appears-after-i-startup-my-laptop-then-it-w)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my GPU was dying, and after replacing it with a fully functional one and reinstalling, it worked.