# Ubuntu doesn't boot - /dev/sdb5: clean, nnn/nnn files, nnn/nnn blocks

Tags: dual-boot, 22.04

I had deleted a few partitions from my disk that I thought was useless. I continued to use my computer normally until I had to restart it and now when I choose Ubuntu (at the dual boot), I receive the following message:

```
[0.1XXX] x86/cpu: SGX disabled by BIOS.
/dev/sdb5: clean, nnn/nnn files, nnn/nnn blocks
You are in emergency mode. After logging in, type "journalctl -xb" to view system logs,
"systemctl reboot" to reboot, "systemctl default" or "exit" to boot into default mode.
Press Enter for maintenance (or press Control-D to continue):
```

I was using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Comment: What did you delete? You did back up everything just in case? Lets see whats left: Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Bootinfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.Lets see details, use ppa version with your USB installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair   &           
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["dev/sda1: clean, ..." This message appears after I startup my laptop, then it won't continue booting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/882385/dev-sda1-clean-this-message-appears-after-i-startup-my-laptop-then-it-w)