# My pc stopped working after I restarted it

Tags: dual-boot

I don't know why my ubuntu20.04 is showing  /dev/nvme0n1p5:clean, 832721/6758400 files, 25867274/27030784 blocks.
It started when I restarted my PC.
How can I resolve it?

Comment: what did you do before restarting the PC?

Comment: the message tells you that your filesystem is fine and that no problems have been found,so the message is most likely unrelated to your bootup problem.please edit your question with more information about what you did before restarting your pc.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["dev/sda1: clean, ..." This message appears after I startup my laptop, then it won't continue booting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/882385/dev-sda1-clean-this-message-appears-after-i-startup-my-laptop-then-it-w)