# Unable to boot Ubuntu with suspend/remove device

Tags: boot, dual-boot

When I try to boot, the following message appears on a black screen:

```
Gave up waiting for suspend/resume device
/dev/sda7: clean, 260106/1534896 files, 5877531/6103296 blocks
```

Comment: Ubuntu release/version? What happened prior to noticing this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["dev/sda1: clean, ..." This message appears after I startup my laptop, then it won't continue booting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/882385/dev-sda1-clean-this-message-appears-after-i-startup-my-laptop-then-it-w)