# Laptop not rebooting ubuntu 21.10

Tags: 21.10, fsck

After running fsck on dev/sda4/manually my laptop is not rebooting.

When rebooting it is showing

```
dev/sda4:recovering journal
devsda4: clean, 1557818/45875700 files, 355817474/183500800 blocks
failed to listen on sylog ticket
Dependency failed for system logging service
```

What can I do?

Comment: There's more you're not telling us. Why did you need to run `fsck`? Also, are you aware that 21.10 will be EOL in less than a week? It's strongly advised that you release upgrade before this happens.

Comment: When I restarted my laptop fsck came upon screem and needed to run . It ckmpleted well but it wont reboot back up

Comment: That would indicate that there's some file system corruption. This could be caused by software behaving unexpectedly, or it could be caused by a failing hard drive. So essentially, it could be anything. Do you have any more information? What kinds of recent actions have you been performing on the device that might have caused new problems?

Comment: Nothing new just coding. My windows partition is working fine

Comment: Have you checked your hardware?  (ie. using SMART as windows will be located on a different part of the disk, and if it's a failing drive, the issue start in one area commonly & expand.. unless it's electrical where the whole drive dies; https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools), or if it's related to the install it's likely a consequence of changes made in the last working session; so I'd ask whomever used it to get details so we can be told what that is, and "*coding*" means what? you were editing text in a text processor? or editing & running commands?  Please be specific.

Comment: When I run in recovery mode it shows failed to start crash report submission daemon and also  failed to start process error reports when automatic report is enabled

Comment: By coding means just writing a python file then it refused to save. Which made me restart my laptop which instructeď  me to run fsck manually. I ran fsck /dev/sda4, completed and exit but on restarting it shows the above error(on the main question) then goes to a blank page with a hyphen. Tried to restart it on    recovery showing a blank screen with a hyphen

Comment: It refused to save??  That rings warning bells like the file-system had *flipped* to RO (read-only) which is a sign of problems (*corruption detected so it flips to RO to prevent data loss*).  Did you explore logs as to why before you rebooted?  Your last comment highlights the need to check hardware & SMART before you use anything like `fsck` as any more writes put data on your drive at risk; and `fsck` will write it errors are detected; ie. should only be done if it's not hardware issue. Check your logs & perform SMART & like hardware checks (same as if it was windows that experienced this)

Comment: There are software problems that can cause the issues; but reading the logs and actual messages that were provided at the first problem are the best way forward. The boot logs that were available (`dmesg` etc) would be lost given reboot (easiest place to look), but systemd journals will still exist, they just don't provide the messages after problem was detected which went to `dmesg` only....  Find & fix the cause; not the symptom; or it'll happen again & again...

Comment: I have performed SMART when in windows saying the health status is GOOD.

Comment: How do I go about the dmesg ?

Comment: You just run `sudo dmesg` to see system messages for the current session (*scroll/page/search as appropriate*); but they are not stored on disk which means if you reboot/shutdown they are lost & you'll see only messages since current boot.  As systemd keeps it journal on disk it's messages can be seen for months/years unless you have a severe problem and *file-system flips* RO where they'll stop being saved; but you look before you reboot/shutdown using `dmesg`.

Comment: how will I run that command and I can't access my terminal

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["dev/sda1: clean, ..." This message appears after I startup my laptop, then it won't continue booting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/882385/dev-sda1-clean-this-message-appears-after-i-startup-my-laptop-then-it-w)